# A norm-decreasing and right-continuous mapping $f: [0,1] \to H$ is of bounded-variation with respect to the norm of $H$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, bounded-variation

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $f:[0,1] \to H$ be a norm-decreasing map in the sense that
\begin{equation}
\lVert f(t_2) \rVert_H \leq \lVert f(t_1) \rVert_H
\end{equation}
if $0 \leq t_1 \leq t_2 \leq 1$.

Suppose further that $f$ is right-continuous in the sense that
\begin{equation}
\lVert f(t+\epsilon)-f(t) \lVert_H \to 0 \text{ as } \epsilon \to 0^+
\end{equation}
for each $t \in [0,1)$.

Then, I wonder if $f$ is of bounded variation with respect to the norm of $H$. That is, do we have
\begin{equation}
\sup\Bigl\{ \sum_{i=1}^n \bigl\lVert f(t_i) -f(t_{i-1})\bigr\rVert_H \mid n \in \mathbb{N}, 0=t_0 < \cdots < t_n=1 \Bigr \} < \infty?
\end{equation}

I cannot find a way myself to bound the sum inside the supremum by using the above condiitons since the norm of $H$ is not necessarily an absolute value...

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to come up with a continuous function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{T}$ with unbounded variation. Then we can take $\mathcal{H}=\mathbb{C}.$ For $h(t)=t\sin (t^{-1})$ we have $|h(t)|\le 1.$ Let $$ f(t)=h(t)+i\sqrt{1-h^2(t)}$$
Then $f$ is continuous and has unbounded variation as its real part has unbounded variation.

Comment: Oh....thank you for your ingenious counterexample...

Comment: Thanks, I have substantially simplified the counterexample to $\mathcal{H}=\mathbb{C}.$

Comment: I would deeply appreciate if you answer this question as well   https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448344/does-the-minlos-theorem-work-for-real-valued-cases-as-well